# Can I not provide filename to DllImport as a compile-time constant?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, dllimport

I'm P/Invoking unmanaged C++ code from managed VB.NET.

My code:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

#Const MyLibPath = "mylib.dll"

Namespace MyLib
   Class A
      <DllImport(MyLibPath)> _
      Public Shared Sub foo()
      End Sub
   End Class
End Namespace
```

I get the error:

> Name 'MyLibPath' not declared

The `filename` argument to `DllImport` is supposed to be constant, so why can I not use `#Const`?

The alternative is writing a string literal, or storing the filename in a `Private Const` variable, but this gets repetitive when I have a number of `DllImport`s for the same DLL spread across different classes. I really just want the one constant.

Comment: You are mixing up Const and #Const.  VB.NET does not have a preprocessor that substitutes identifiers like C does.  A #Const is only usable in #If expressions.  Use Const instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comment, the VB.NET compiler does not have a complete C style preprocessor.  Any #Const you define in code or in the project properties can only be used in #If expressions.

Use a Const instead (no #).

Avoid making them Public btw, that tends to cause accidents when you ship bug fixes.  Their value is directly compiled into IL so changing a Const value doesn't not automatically update the value used in another assembly that you don't recompile or ship as part of the bug fix.  Don't go beyond Friend.

Comment: Oh, it doesn't preprocess into arbitrary statements? Well, there's my answer then. D'oh! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible approach to solving this problem: move the constant into a common class:

```
Public Class Common
    Public Const MyLibPath As String = "mylib.dll"
End Class
```

and then reference the imports from that class:

```
Class A
    <DllImport(Common.MyLibPath)> _
    Public Shared Sub foo()
    End Sub
End Class
```

or (assuming the namespace of the common class is WindowsApplication1):

```
Imports WindowsApplication1.Common

Class A
    <DllImport(MyLibPath)> _
    Public Shared Sub foo()
    End Sub
End Class
```